# Oauth2.0 Authentication code generation from client id and secret in Apex code

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, oauth2, authorization

I am not able to get the Authorisation code  Oauth2.0 from Apex code, However i can get the same from Postman callout. Is it possible to get the authorisation code from apex? I am using the below source in the anonymous window of Developer Console. In developer console the response is 20:03:06:194 CALLOUT_RESPONSE [23]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]

```
    string ClientId = '*******';
    string ClientSecret = '*********';
    string endpoint ='https://**********/services/api/oauth2/token';

    string body = 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=All';
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(ClientId + ':' + ClientSecret);
    String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' +  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    system.debug('Encoder Value' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue));

    // Construct the request
    http http = new http();
    httpRequest request = new httpRequest();
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    request.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded ');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
    request.setBody(body);
    System.debug('request*****'+request);

    // Send the request
    httpResponse Res = http.send(request);
    system.debug('response status code ' + Res.getStatusCode() );
```

The header in postman tool is as below

Request Headers
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic MW***********************TUzZDkzMzM5MDRhYWJkYjdjZmE2OTI5MDI0ZjUx
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 80cf**********d98
Host: *******.c***d.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 39
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=k**********
▶
Request Body
grant_type:
"client_credentials"
scope:
"All"

Comment: Wait for Winter '24 - you'll be able to do [`client_credentials` with Named Creds out of the box](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_named_credentials_clientcredentials.htm&release=246&type=5)

Comment: I tried to check the same in the Developer Preview org of Winter 24. However, i am not able to fetch that named credential in the Apex code.  I have created the External credential, Added principal to it, The prinicipal is configured with client id and client secret. the permission set is also assigned.

Comment: please edit your question with these details. Take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is your goal here.